# How to create a libJSON library?

Tags: libjson

I downloaded C++ libJSON from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/):

And they suggest me to use it as a library. How can I create library using the code they have provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must have installed g++ and make in console/terminal just compile it type `make`, it will produce `libjson.a` which is static libary. When you create you C/C++ program you can link it with it `g++ -l libjson.a`

and in your code include libJSON.h header file.

```
#include "libJSON.h"
```

and you can use all functions from that header file.

On windows you must Install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (GNU utilities for Windows), or IDE like [DevC++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) or [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) (Code::Blocks use MinGW). You can also use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) unix like environment for windows (but when you compile file in cygwin you can run it only in Cygwin)

In Code::Blocks when you create project you can set additinal library which will be linked with your executable.

Comment: can you detail the steps to create lib file?

Comment: This worked in MAc. Can you guide me how to do it in Windows?

Comment: "it will produce libjson.a which is shared libary" -- libjson.a is a static archive, not a shared library.  To make the shared library (which is an ".so" file), you must use `SHARED=1 make`

Answer (score 4):

i was trying to compile libjson 7.6.1 for Visual Studio 2010. And was facing some difficulties in compiling it. What i did was

1. Download Libjson
2. open libjson.vcproj and goto line 240. You will find a missing ">". Type it in and save the file.
3. Now this can be used to build dynamic and static lib.

A simple thing wasted my couple of hours. Hope it saves some of yours.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works for more recent versions of Visual studio (e.g. 2015) which otherwise fail to complete the conversion to the mare recent project format.