# Building with libjson on OSX Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mavericks, libjson

I've tried the advice on threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495357/cannot-install-libjson-in-c-embedding-in-xcode-4-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842976/using-libjson-in-a-c-project) to no avail.

I have Xcode 5.0.2 installed and I am compiling everything on the command line. After make/make install to build libjson, I created a simple test file to link and build from it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libjson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    JSONNode n(JSON_NODE);
    n.push_back(JSONNode("RootA", "Hello World"));
    JSONNode c(JSON_ARRAY);
    c.set_name("ArrayOfNumbers");
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 16));
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 42));
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 128));
    n.push_back(c);
    std::string jc = n.write_formatted();
    std::cout << jc << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build this file:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG main.cpp -ljson
```

I get this:

```
main.cpp:17:5: error: unknown type name 'JSONNode'
    JSONNode n(JSON_NODE);
    ^
main.cpp:18:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSONNode'
    n.push_back(JSONNode("RootA", "Hello World"));
                ^
main.cpp:19:5: error: unknown type name 'JSONNode'
    JSONNode c(JSON_ARRAY);
    ^
main.cpp:21:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSONNode'
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 16));
                ^
main.cpp:22:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSONNode'
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 42));
                ^
main.cpp:23:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JSONNode'
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 128));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a libjson library to link to xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010975/creating-a-libjson-library-to-link-to-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010975/creating-a-libjson-library-to-link-to-xcode) after I realized the make process had problems. Basically, the solution is to copy the source code into Xcode and build it as part of the project instead of trying to link it as a library.

I also tried to build libjson 7.6.1 on an ubuntu machine (12.04) and encountered the exact problem despite a perfect make.